# VBA Error "Expected Function or Variable" when trying to set a PowerPoint Slide

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have following code -

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPTObj As Object
Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim oGraph As Graph.Chart
Dim oAxis As Graph.Axis
Dim SlideNum As Integer
Dim strPresPath As String, strNewPresPath As String

strPresPath = "Location.ppt"
strNewPresPath = "Destination.ppt"

'instantiate the powerpoint application and make it visible
Set oPPTObj = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
oPPTObj.Visible = msoCTrue

Set oPPTFile = oPPTObj.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
SlideNum = 1

Set oPPTSlide = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
Set oPPTShape = oPPTSlide.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

oPPTSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 20, 300, 5

With oPPTSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
    .text = "ALL BSE"
    .Font.Color = vbWhite
    .Font.Underline = msoFalse
End With

End Sub
```

I get an error

> Expected Function or Variable

at the following line:

```
Set oPPTSlide = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't `Set` and `Select` at the same line, try `Set oPPTSlide = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum)` (there's almost never any reason to use `Select`). Your code doesn't need it, and it will only will slow your run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment above, you can't `Set` and `Select` at the same line (also, there's almost never any reason to use `Select`). Try `Set oPPTSlide = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum)`

However, a few "upgrades" to your code:

Directly set the `oPPTShape` with the new created `Shapes` with :

```
Set oPPTShape = oPPTSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 20, 300, 5)
```

and afterwards, easily modify the `oPPTShape` properties, using the `With` statement below:

```
With oPPTShape.TextFrame.TextRange
    .text = "ALL BSE"
    .Font.Color = vbWhite
    .Font.Underline = msoFalse
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be...

```
Set oPPTSlide = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum)
```

Comment: remove the `Select` from you answer, this is not a good advise to give, `Select` should be avoided in all cases